# python print out is not in the same line

Tags: python, printing, output

I have question, when I try to pint out following things in python in the sameline,
the actually output is not exactly as I expected.

```
for cl in lines:
    filename="superfamily_new_trail_"+str(cl)
    a=filename.strip()
    f=open(a,'r')
    lines2=f.readlines()
    for line2 in lines2:
        if (not "====="  in line2) and (not"CDD" in line2)and (len(line2)>30):
            Tag=line2.split("\t") 
            print cl+"\t"+Tag[0]+"\t"+Tag[7]+"\t"+Tag[10]
```

I was hoping my output would be

```
cl    Tag[0]    Tag[7]       Tag[10]
```

but my actually print out is like

```
cl 
       Tag[0]    Tag[7]     Tag[10]
```

in two different lines?
what's wrong with it?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does `print repr(Tag)` show you? It appears there is an extra carriage return character somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have a newline in `cl`.  You can do this:

```
clStr = str(cl).rstrip()
print clStr+"\t"+Tag[0]+"\t"+Tag[7]+"\t"+Tag[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `cl` string has an extra newline at the end. Strip it:

```
print cl.rstrip('\n')+"\t"+Tag[0]+"\t"+Tag[7]+"\t"+Tag[10]
```

This is quite normal for lines read from a file; the `\n` escape sequence stands for a newline.